# iOS build on PC paired to Mac - app.dSYM.zip fails, 'Show IPA File on Build Server' missing, errSecInternalComponent, 'IPA is not a valid zipfile'

Tags: build, xamarin.ios, zip, app-store, ipa

I have a Xamarin iOS application in VisualStudio 2019 on a Windows 10 PC. I build it on the PC, and when possible then right click the project and choose Show IPA File on Build Server, then on my Mac I upload the file to the app store using Transporter. I am encountering these issues:

1. Whenever I build, the build says it failed with message "There was an error unzipping the file bin\Ad-Hoc\MyApp.app.dSYM.zip: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\MyDirectory\MyApp.iOS\bin\Ad-Hoc\MyAppiOS.app.dSYM'." This has not historically caused any issues - we have still been able to upload the IPA to the app store and deploy our app - but I include it in case it's relevant to the other issues.
2. Sometimes, my build fails saying it "has been disconnected while waiting a post repsonse to topic xvs/Build/.../execute-task/MyApp.iOS/...Codesign" or "Unable to connect to Mac Server with Address='192.111.111.111' and User='My Username'. The build can't continue without a connection". I'm assuming a wifi issue must cause this, though the machines are all right next to one another and next to my router so seems odd. Occasionally when I try to pair to the Mac, I also get the message "Error, Couldn't connect to com. Please try again. An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions." In any case, makes me wonder if there's any way for me to 1) hardwire the Mac to the PC or 2) build directly on the Mac instead of through VS on the PC, even though I write the code on the PC?
3. During the build, I periodically get an error "/Users/myUser/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyApp.iOS//bin/Ad-Hoc/MyAppiOS.app: errSecInternalComponent MyApp.iOS   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets 2003". If I lock all keychains on the Mac this goes away on the next build, but then it reappears a few builds later.
4. Once the build finishes with just the .dSym.zip error, most of the time, the "Show IPA File on Build Server" option still does NOT show up (not greyed out - it is not present in the menu at all) when I right click the iOS project. To get around this, I have been copying the file over to the Mac via S3. I'm wondering why the option doesn't show up, and if there's a way to just find the built file on the Mac rather than copying it over from Windows?
5. I then use Transporter on the Mac to upload the IPA file to the Apple Store. It always is able to read the version information and says the file is Delivered. However, often I then get an email from Apple saying the build failed because "ITMS-90688: This IPA is invalid - While unzipping the IPA we received the error message [ End-of-central-directory signature not found. Either this file is not a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive. In the latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on the last disk(s) of this archive. unzip: cannot find zipfile directory in one of MyAppiOS.ipa or MyAppiOS.ipa.zip, and cannot find MyAppiOS.ipa.ZIP, period. ] Verify that the IPA can be unzipped before reattempting your upload.".
6. In response to that error, I've tried to unzip the IPA file and I find that on the PC it is always unzippable if I change the extension to .zip, and on my Mac, I can always unzip it to see the Payload directory, and the MyAppiOS item inside it can never be opened - I get a popup "You can't open the application 'MyAppiOS' because it is not supported on this type of Mac." - in any case, the files Apple likes and the ones it doesn't look the same to me when I try unzipping.

My only ideas are to try to figure out how to open and build the app on my Mac, to call my router company, and to keep trying and trying, over and over again, until finally one of the builds works... which sometimes literally takes hours.

Many thanks for any help you are able to offer!

Comment: The error message seems similar to this one https://askubuntu.com/a/54955 Tiy cab aksi try to fix the zip file using this https://osxdaily.com/2019/05/12/how-to-fix-unzip-error-end-of-central-directory-signature-not-found/ When you create the IPA, are there any other files created in that folder? Is your internet speed slow? When you archive the iOS project directly in the Mac (instead of using the windows), do you still see the same issue? Are you using the latest updates on both devices?

Comment: Many thanks @Saamer for the suggestions! I'm not sure how to fix the zipfile because I don't know it's broken until after I submit it to the Apple store, at which point it's my understanding that I need to build it fresh with a new version number for resubmit? I don't know how to archive the iOS project directly in the Mac but agree that will be a good thing to try to figure out when I get some time. When I update VS on the PC and then Pair to Mac, I let it update the Mac's VS and I upgrade XCode if prompted. My internet speed is very fast, though I do have occasional connectivity issues.

Comment: Here's how you archive on your Mac using VS for Mac https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTXa9Ubyh3A

Comment: I have been having this same problem  you described on #1. I could never be able to complete a release build without a work around. the work around is watching the "iOS\bin\iPhone" folder when compiling is in progress and quickly copy this folder MyAppName.iOS.app.dSYM to this folder manually if it disappears.  If not build would fail 100% of the time, I did not know what caused it. If you ever find a solution for this, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Also notice that during the compiling process. this folder keeps getting deleted again and again. so I have to keep paste it back again and again to keep  build process survives.